# Cleaning Up Left-Over Elements w/ Batch Processing, Java SDK

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a problem where I am loosely following this blog post which I have found on other questions: https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/

I read a bounded PCollection from BQ that has a list of elements. Then, every n elements, I batch it using the BagState and then flush. However, I cannot set-up an expiry timer to clean-up elements if they are left over in the BagState after the last flush.

The bounded PCollection seems to have a global window from my readings. Any way I try to set an expiry timer on it, I get an error about how it is past the last timestamp for the window.

Is there a way to clean it up such that I can set the expiry so that once the last element executes, I can clean-up whatever is left in the buffer?

```
@StateId("buffer")
private final StateSpec<BagState<User>> bufferedEvents = StateSpecs.bag();
@StateId("count")
private final StateSpec<ValueState<Integer>> countState = StateSpecs.value();
@TimerId("expiry")
private final TimerSpec expirySpec = TimerSpecs.timer(TimeDomain.EVENT_TIME);

@ProcessElement
    public void processElement(BoundedWindow window,
                               @Element KV<Integer, User> user,
                               @StateId("buffer") BagState<User> bufferState,
                               @StateId("count") ValueState<Integer> countState,
                               @TimerId("expiry") Timer expiryTimer,
                               OutputReceiver<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>> out) {
        //expiryTimer.set(BoundedWindow.TIMESTAMP_MAX_VALUE)...I've tried everything.
        try {
            currentBundleElementCount++;
            int count = Objects.firstNonNull(countState.read(), 0);
            count = count + 1;
            countState.write(count);
            bufferState.add(user.getValue());
            if (count > MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
                for (AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String> entry : processUsers(bufferState.read())) {
                    out.output(entry);
                }
                countState.clear();
                bufferState.clear();
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            out.output(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(user.getValue().uuid(), t.getMessage()));
        }
    }

@OnTimer("expiry")
    public void onExpiry(
            @StateId("buffer") BagState<User> bufferState,
            OutputReceiver<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>> out) {
        LOGGER.info("Firing the clean-up function, should only fire once per bundle");
        if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(bufferState.isEmpty().read())) {
            for (AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String> entry : processUsers(bufferState.read())) {
                out.output(entry);
            }
            bufferState.clear();
        }
    }
```